# Create nested attribute for a new column in a data frame

Tags: r, attributes, label, structure, attr

I'm working with data that has certain labels (like is common in social science research). In particular, here the values in a column are not stored as a factor but as a numeric column that contains labels (as attributes). And these labels in turn have attributes (the names of the label).

Now, I know how I can change the names of the labels for existing columns. But I fail to do so for new columns or to me more precise: I know how I can create them with dedicated packages, but I'm wondering if there's a native/base R option with e.g. `attr`, `attributes` or `structure`.

example data:

```
df <- structure(list(Q16_3 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 1, 0, 1),
                                       label = "Q16_3 question label",
                                       format.spss = "F8.2",
                                       labels = c(`Not Selected` = 0, Selected = 1),
                                       class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")),
                     Q16_4 = structure(c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1),
                                       label = "Q16_4 question label",
                                       format.spss = "F8.2",
                                       labels = c(`Not Selected` = 0, Selected = 1),
                                       class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"))),
                row.names = c(NA, -10L),
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

E.g. `df %>% count(Q16_4)` gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
              Q16_4     n
*         <dbl+lbl> <int>
1  0 [Not Selected]     2
2  1 [Selected]         4
3 NA                    4
```

Now I'm creating a column and trying to create a "labels" attribute, but it fails to show up:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(test = rep(1:2, 5))

df$test <- structure(df$test, labels = c("NO" = 1, "YES" = 2))

df %>%
  count(test)
```

only gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   test     n
* <int> <int>
1     1     5
2     2     5
```

I guess it has sth. to do with the structure of the attributes itself, because they look different:

```
str(df)

tibble [10 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Q16_3: dbl+lbl [1:10] NA, NA,  1,  1,  1, NA, NA,  1,  0,  1
   ..@ label      : chr "Q16_3 question label"
   ..@ format.spss: chr "F8.2"
   ..@ labels     : Named num [1:2] 0 1
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "1 Selected" "2 Selected"
 $ Q16_4: dbl+lbl [1:10] NA, NA,  1,  1,  1, NA, NA,  0,  0,  1
   ..@ label      : chr "Q16_4 question label"
   ..@ format.spss: chr "F8.2"
   ..@ labels     : Named num [1:2] 0 1
   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "NO NO" "YES YES"
 $ test : int [1:10] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:2] 1 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "NO" "YES"
```

Long story short: how would I need to change my code to allow for creating such "nested" attributes?

Comment: What output are you expecting? I am not sure if I have understood it correctly.

Comment: Not an aggregated output. I want to change it in the data (so that it correctly shows up in the output). So in the first example, it's a "correct" labels in the data and also shows in the count table. In my second example, it seems to be ok in the data (but I guess it's not), because it doesn't show up in the output. So idea would be to add the labels to the data in a way that it would render the same output as in my first example.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the labels using `attr` and use `match` to replace them.

```
var <- attr(df$test, 'labels')
df$test_label <- names(var)[match(df$test, var)]
df

#               Q16_3             Q16_4  test test_label
#           <dbl+lbl>         <dbl+lbl> <int> <chr>     
# 1 NA                NA                    1 NO        
# 2 NA                NA                    2 YES       
# 3  1 [Selected]      1 [Selected]         1 NO        
# 4  1 [Selected]      1 [Selected]         2 YES       
# 5  1 [Selected]      1 [Selected]         1 NO        
# 6 NA                NA                    2 YES       
# 7 NA                NA                    1 NO        
# 8  1 [Selected]      0 [Not Selected]     2 YES       
# 9  0 [Not Selected]  0 [Not Selected]     1 NO        
#10  1 [Selected]      1 [Selected]         2 YES
```

If you want to replace the original `test` column assign it to `df$test <-`  above.

---

In your original dataframe what you have is haven labelled data which can be constructed in this way :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(test = haven::labelled(rep(1:2, 5), labels = c("NO" = 1, "YES" = 2)))

#          Q16_3             Q16_4      test
#           <dbl+lbl>         <dbl+lbl> <int+lbl>
# 1 NA                NA                  1 [NO] 
# 2 NA                NA                  2 [YES]
# 3  1 [Selected]      1 [Selected]       1 [NO] 
# 4  1 [Selected]      1 [Selected]       2 [YES]
# 5  1 [Selected]      1 [Selected]       1 [NO] 
# 6 NA                NA                  2 [YES]
# 7 NA                NA                  1 [NO] 
# 8  1 [Selected]      0 [Not Selected]   2 [YES]
# 9  0 [Not Selected]  0 [Not Selected]   1 [NO] 
#10  1 [Selected]      1 [Selected]       2 [YES]
```

It's labels will also show up in `count`  :

```
df %>%
  mutate(test = haven::labelled(rep(1:2, 5),labels = c("NO" = 1, "YES" = 2))) %>%
  count(test)

#      test     n
#* <int+lbl> <int>
#1   1 [NO]      5
#2   2 [YES]     5
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only changes the aggregated output table. I'd need it in the data.

Comment: Just to understand it: this code would be in addition to my setting of the labels above, and it would change the variable to a character one, right? It wouldn't keep the numeric structure of the data and adds the labels as an attribute?

Comment: What you have in your original data is haven labelled data, you can have similar format in the new data as well (check the updated answer) but it is not base R.

Comment: Yep, was wondering if there was an easy base R wayv to "copy" the haven::labelled behaviour, i.e. creating a numeric variable that has nice labels. But ok for me to go the way through the dedicated package.